# How to use a list with spatial dataframes in a for loop? - R

Tags: r, spatial-database, list, for-loop

I have three spatial dataframes (polygons), created via [this tutorial](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/202536_7a122ff56e9f4062b6b012d9921afd80.html). The three spatial dataframes must be exported as shapefiles via a for loop. I created a list `polygons` containing the three spatial dataframes. Each spatial dataframe should be treated as a separate item that is used in the for loop. However, when I run the for loop, the first item of the `polygons` is used three times, resulting in 3 shapefiles that have the same coordinates (i.e. the coordinates of spatial dataframe 1). In case I access the second item of the list `polygons` via `polygons[[2]]` the information corresponding to the second item is shown nevertheless.

Each iteration in the for loop should take the corresponding item (i.e. spatial dataframe) of the list, eventually resulting in three shapefiles that are situated at different locations - How can I do this?

code:

```
library(sp)
library(sf)

## create spatial dataframe 1 

FID_df1 <-  c(1)
x_coord <- c(16.48438,  17.49512,  24.74609, 22.59277, 16.48438)
y_coord <- c(59.736328125, 55.1220703125, 55.0341796875, 61.142578125, 59.736328125)
xym <- cbind(x_coord, y_coord)
xym

p = Polygon(xym)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
plot(sps)

proj4string(sps) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
sps$FID_df1 <- FID_df1

## create spatial dataframe 2

FID_df2 <-  c(1)
x_coord2 <- c(18.48438,  19.49512,  26.74609, 24.59277, 18.48438)
y_coord2 <- c(61.736328125, 57.1220703125, 57.0341796875, 63.142578125, 61.736328125)
xym2 <- cbind(x_coord2, y_coord2)
xym2

p2 = Polygon(xym2)
ps2 = Polygons(list(p2),1)
sps2 = SpatialPolygons(list(ps2))
plot(sps2)

proj4string(sps2) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
sps2$FID_df2 <- FID_df2
view(sps2)

## create spatial dataframe 3

FID_df3 <-  c(1)
x_coord3 <- c(-118.48438,  -119.49512,  -126.74609, -124.59277, -118.48438)
y_coord3 <- c(35.736328125, 33.1220703125, 33.0341796875, 37.142578125, 35.736328125)
xym3 <- cbind(x_coord3, y_coord3)
xym3

p3 = Polygon(xym3)
ps3 = Polygons(list(p3),1)
sps3 = SpatialPolygons(list(ps3))
plot(sps3)

proj4string(sps3) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
sps3$FID_df3 <- FID_df3
view(sps3)

## for loop - export every spatial dataframe as shapefile

#initialize list with different spatial dataframes that need to be exported as shapefile
#assign the spatial dataframes to variables with identical names. These variables can be used in the for loop
polygons = list(sps = sps, sps2 = sps2, sps3 = sps3)

#initialize list with different values to insert into the shapefile name, relating to the different spatial dataframes
numbers = list(1, 2, 3)

#for loop - write every spatial dataframe as shapefile
for(polygon in polygons)
{ for(num in numbers)
  {
  sf_polygon <- st_as_sf(polygon)
  layer <- paste("poly", num, sep = "")
  print(layer) #verify
  sf::st_write(sf_polygon, dsn='C:/Test',layer=layer, driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use two `for` loop for this case. Actually, with two `for()` loops you're iterating 9 times in total. Just simply use a positional index (integer 1:n) for this purpose:

```
for(i in seq_along(polygons)){
  layer <- paste0('poly',i,'.shp') # less characters than paste(sep='')
  print(layer)
  write_sf(st_as_sf(polygons[[i]]),layer)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `lapply` as your iterator. Please note that I added `SpatialPolygonsDataFram`e to your workflow as there are issues in exporting a shapefile with an empty attribute table.

```
library(sp)
library(sf)

polygons <- vector(mode = "list", length = 3)
polygons[[1]] <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(  
  SpatialPolygons((list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(
         c(16.48438, 17.49512,24.74609, 22.59277, 16.48438), 
         c(59.736328125, 55.1220703125, 55.0341796875, 61.142578125, 59.736328125)))), 
         "1"))), proj4string = CRS("EPSG:4326")), data.frame(ID=1)) 
polygons[[2]] <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame( 
  SpatialPolygons((list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(
         c(18.48438,  19.49512,  26.74609, 24.59277, 18.48438), 
         c(61.736328125, 57.1220703125, 57.0341796875, 63.142578125, 61.736328125)))), 
         "1"))), proj4string = CRS("EPSG:4326")), data.frame(ID=2)) 
polygons[[3]] <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(   
  SpatialPolygons((list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(
         c(-118.48438,  -119.49512,  -126.74609, -124.59277, -118.48438), 
         c(35.736328125, 33.1220703125, 33.0341796875, 37.142578125, 35.7363281255)))), 
         "1"))), proj4string = CRS("EPSG:4326")) , data.frame(ID=3))
```

Here we use an internal iterator using the "parent.frame" object call.

```
lapply(polygons, function(x){
  i = parent.frame()$i
  sf::write_sf(sf::st_as_sf(polygons[[i]]),
               paste0("poly_", i, ".shp"))})
```

Here, we specify the iterator using `seq_along`.

```
lapply(seq_along(polygons), function(i) {
  sf::write_sf(sf::st_as_sf(polygons[[i]]),
               paste0("poly", i,".shp"))})
```

You could save yourself quite a bit of headache by skipping sp entirely and just using sf. First, create a single data.frame with an ID field associated with the coordinates.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

( xy <- rbind(
data.frame(ID=1, x=c(16.48438, 17.49512,24.74609, 22.59277, 16.48438), 
y=c(59.736328125, 55.1220703125, 55.0341796875, 61.142578125, 59.736328125)),
data.frame(ID=2, x=c(18.48438,  19.49512,  26.74609, 24.59277, 18.48438), 
y=c(61.736328125, 57.1220703125, 57.0341796875, 63.142578125, 61.736328125)),
data.frame(ID=3, x=c(-118.48438,  -119.49512,  -126.74609, -124.59277, -118.48438), 
y=c(35.736328125, 33.1220703125, 33.0341796875, 37.142578125, 35.7363281255))) )
```

Now, use st_as_sf to coerce to sf, group_by to create MULTIPOINT data for representing each polygon and then cast into a POLYGON.

```
xy <- xy %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
      summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
        st_cast("POLYGON")
```

You can now iterate through the single POLYGON feature class object rather than having a list.

```
lapply(unique(xy$ID), function(i){
  sf::write_sf(xy[xy$ID == i,],
  paste0("poly_", i, ".shp"))})
```